# How to automatically enable button when the value is positive without click anywhere

Tags: javascript, html, button

i want to ask how to enable the button when the value shown is positive and disable the button when the value shown is negative automatically WITHOUT click anywhere.

Because my current problem is, i want the button automatically change to enable when the value is positive without to click somewhere. But right now, when the value is shown, i need to click somewhere, then then button with change to enable from disable..

Please help me

This is my html

```
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <label class="text-capitalize text-danger">Change</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">RM</span>
            <div class="form-control input-mimic" id="change_amount"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my js

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#modal-redeem #redeem_tendered_amount", function(e) {
  var tendered_amt = this;
  var tendered_amt_bank = $('#redeem_tendered_amount_bank');
  calculateChange(tendered_amt, tendered_amt_bank, "#modal-redeem #redeem_payable", "#modal-redeem #redeem_change_amount");
});

$("body").on("keyup", "#modal-redeem #redeem_tendered_amount_bank", function(e) {
  var tendered_amt_bank = this;
  var tendered_amt = $('#redeem_tendered_amount');
  calculateChange(tendered_amt, tendered_amt_bank, "#modal-redeem #redeem_payable", "#modal-redeem #redeem_change_amount");
});

$("#redeem_tendered_amount").on("change", function() {
  showHideRedeemButton();
});

$("#redeem_tendered_amount_bank").on("change", function() {
  showHideRedeemButton();
});

function showHideRedeemButton() {
  var change_amt = $('#redeem_change_amount').text();
  if (change_amt < 0) {
    document.getElementById("confirm_redeem").disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("confirm_redeem").disabled = false;
  }
}
```

After inserting the value and the change > 0, then the 'Redeem' button will be disabled, but i need to click somewhere else first. I want it automatically change without click anywhere

[image: After inserting the value and the change > 0, then the 'Redeem' button will be disabled, but i need to click somewhere else first. I want it automatically change without click anywhere]

Comment: Use the `change` event on the element to run code when the value is updated.

Comment: which element sir? @Barmar

Comment: Whichever element you want to conditionalize on.

Comment: Never mind, I misunderstood. The `change` event isn't triggered until you click out of the field that you're editing. Put the call to `showHideRedeemButton()` in the `keyup` handlers after you call `calculateChange()`.